# General question - How do I familiarize myself with a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: database, postgresql

I just started a new job recently and I'm trying to learn all of the bits and pieces of the database but I've never done a job like this before. It seems like it's difficult to go about it in a systematic way without some kind of in-depth documentation on everything which doesn't exist at the moment as I'm at a startup. It's in PostgreSQL, I'm not sure what other information you guys'll need to help me out. I'm learning SQL and have plenty of resources I can use to improve there, but are there any exercises or ways of studying the database that I can use to better familiarize myself with the underlying logic and what all of the individual tables/columns/views are and how they relate. If there's any other information that would help you to help me then just let me know and I'll provide it as best I can.

Comment: It would probably help to look at the application code that uses it, if it's not too complex to read.

Answer (score 0):

I use [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) from JetBrains to explore databases and for creating queries. DataGrip also has a handy tool to diagram relationships between tables. Unfortunately, the tool is not free, but it comes in handy for sure.

There are many great database tools available online; DataGrip just happens to be the one I use most.

Also, there is a great post on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-learn-SQL-What-are-some-good-online-resources-like-websites-blogs-or-videos) with plenty of links to learning resources.

Good luck with your new job.

[DataGrip's Diagram tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCGX0.png)

Comment: Besides the previously mentioned - all good -  each version of Postgres documentation comes with a [tutorial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/tutorial.html). Read it.  Also, scan the questions posted here and at least mentally try to give an answer ( even if that is just like "well maybe an outer join instead of an inner join" or "maybe  function abc would do that". Then look at the answers. You'll be surprised how quickly you begin to see patterns. Also, forget loops try to start thinking in sets of things not individual rows. And when in doubt ask here.

Comment: Thanks Oscar, I'm gonna give DataGrip a shot. Looks pretty cool!